# Having trouble using xt::where in xtensor

Tags: c++, numpy, xtensor

I am trying to find an index value of certain array values in an xarray. I have an xarray called `lattice` filled that contains numbers 1 through n and what I would like is something like

```
auto x2 = xt::where(lattice == i)
```

to get the index values of element `i` in `lattice` that will be used for a distance function, but I get the message that `==` doesn't match the operands. The problem doesn't happen when I use `>` so I'm just wondering what the difference is.

I've used `np.where(lattice==i)` in python and I'm trying to translate it over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use `xt::equal(a, b)` instead of `a == b`. Indeed this is different from for example `a > b` which is completely the same as `xt::greater(a, b)`.

Note also that the list of indices can be converted to a matrix using `xt::from_indices(...)`, see [documentation](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/indices.html). Consider the following example:

```cpp
#include <xtensor/xtensor.hpp>
#include <xtensor/xio.hpp>

int main()
{
    xt::xtensor<size_t,2> a = xt::arange(5 * 5).reshape({5, 5});
    size_t i = 4;
    xt::xtensor<size_t,2> idx = xt::from_indices(xt::where(xt::equal(a, i)));
    std::cout << idx << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```